# Translate query combined max and min from mysql to mongoDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

My documents look like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5698fcb5585b2de0120eba31"),
  "id": "26125242313",
  "parent_id": "26125241841",
  "link_id": "10024080",
  "name": "26125242313",
  "author": "gigaquack",
  "body": "blogging = creative writing",
  "subreddit_id": "6",
  "subreddit": "reddit.com",
  "score": "27",
  "created_utc": "2007-10-22 18:39:31"
}
```

And i was using mysql databse. And i use this query:

```
Select max(score), author from (select sum(score) as score,
author as author from reddit where author in 
(select distinct author from reddit) group by author)
union
Select min(score), author from (select sum(score) as score, 
author as author from reddit where author in 
(select distinct author from reddit) group by author)
```

Now i want to translate this query into mongoDB. How should i do that?
Sorry for unclear question. I want a query that calculates how much score users have and show the max combined score and min combined score with their username. Like:

```
 xxxx|150   yyyy|2
```

Comment: Did you realize the `score` field is a String and you can only apply arithmetic expressions on numerical fields when using aggregation framework?

Comment: Instead of saying *I want to translate this query into MongoDB* please tell use what you are trying to do here and show us the expected result.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or translation service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question,basically i want to add up score of every single user to check which user have the most combined score